# SoapServer set attribute for Body

Tags: php, xml, soap

In PHP by using SoapServer class I can create response message.

Is it possible to set attribute to body tag in response?

PHP code

```
ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer('myWsdl.wsdl');
$server->addFunction("GetDetails");
$server->handle();
```

Current outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetDetailsResponse/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Expected outcome:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body Id="some_id">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can try something along the lines of:

```
ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer('myWsdl.wsdl');
$server->addFunction("GetDetails");

ob_start();
$server->handle();
$soap = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$soap = str_replace("<SOAP-ENV:Body>", '<SOAP-ENV:Body Id="some_id">', $soap);

$length = strlen($soap);
header("Content-Length: ".$length);

echo $soap;
```

Of course if `str_replace()` makes you feel a little dirty, you can always load `$soap` up as a `DOMDocument` and manipulate it there.